# Uniqueness in Bochner's theorem

Tags: harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

> Bochner's theorem : Let $G$ be a locally compact Abelian group. Then
>   for any $ \phi \in \ P(G) $  there is a unique positive Radon measure
>   $ \ μ  \in \ $ M ($ \widehat{G} $) such that 
>                                $ \phi (x) = \int_{ \widehat{G} }  \beta(x) ~ \mathrm{d}{μ(\beta)} $

Uniqueness: Suppose
$ \int_{ \widehat{G} }  \beta(x) ~ \mathrm{d}{μ(\beta)}  = 0 $ for all $  x \in \ G $ with some (not necesseary positive) Radon measure $μ$.
Then it holds

$$ 0=\int_{ {G} }  \int_{ \widehat{G} } f(x)   \beta(x) ~ \mathrm{d}{μ(\beta) d(x)    }. \quad \ (1)  $$      for all  $  f \in  { {L^{1}}(G) }   $.

${ \widehat{{L^{1}}(G)} }$ is dense in $C0(\widehat{G})$
and hence this implies $ μ = 0  \quad \ (2) $.
suppose that $ μ_1 $and $   μ_2 $ are two positive Radon measure that satisfied in theorem.let $μ= μ_1-   μ_2 $.by (2) we have $ μ_1=   μ_2 \quad \ (3)$

> My question:I do not understand why $ μ = 0$? is (3) correct?

I will be grateful if you help me.

Comment: The fact that $\mu=0$ is based on the Riesz representation theorem: $C_0$ is dual to the space of finite Radon measures.