# $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: topological-groups, harmonic-analysis

$ \mathbb{T} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ z \in \mathbb{C}  : |z| = 1 \}$
$\widehat{\mathbb{T}} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{Hom}(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{T})$

To show that $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{Z}$, we need to construct a 1-1 correspondence $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$→$\mathbb{Z}$. Define such a correspondence as follows:
$$  \phi :\mathbb{Z}→\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$$
by $$ \phi(n)= β_n   $$where $ β_n$(α)=$α^n  $   for all $  α \in \ \mathbb{T} $ .
I know that $\mathbb{T} $ ≅$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z }$   by $γ:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z } → \mathbb{T } $  that maps t to $e^{2πit}$.
I'd going to show :

> every $  β \in\ \widehat{\mathbb{T}} $ gives rise to an element in
>   $\mathbb{Z }$

can you help me?

Comment: One way is to lift the homomorphism to the universal coverings.

Comment: Will you please explain more?

Comment: Every $\beta\in \widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ has a unique lift $\tilde{\beta} \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\tilde{\beta}(0) = 0$. That is a homomorphism $(\mathbb{R},+)\to (\mathbb{R},+)$ taking $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Excuse me!unique lift?

Comment: I gather you don't know any covering theory yet? Sorry for not asking first. Do you know $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ already? If you do, you can determine $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ from that by composing with $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$.

Comment: I don't know any things about covering theory.You say that every character of T is the characters of R.it's correct?

Comment: No, that is a misunderstanding. Only, if $\beta\in\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$, then $\beta\circ \eta \in \widehat{\mathbb{R}}$, where $\eta\colon t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$. That gives you an embedding of $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ into $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$, and if you know what $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ is, you can characterise the characters coming from $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ in a simple way.

Comment: I'm confused. Sorry.dual of R
is the set of all continuous homomorphisms from R to T,but I want to show β∈Z?

Comment: You don't want to show that $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$, but that $\beta(z) = z^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If you already know that $\widehat{\mathbb{R}} = \{ t \mapsto e^{2\pi i ct} : c\in\mathbb{R}\}$, it is not difficult to see that those elements of $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ that can be written as $\beta\circ\eta$ for some $\beta\in\widehat{\mathbb{T}}$ are exactly those where $c\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: oh,yes.thank you very much.I'm studying this unit myself alone.It is difficult for me to understand some problems.I have a problem. Could you help me?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838179/uniqueness-in-bochners-theorem